# How to install emacs 26 instead of latest emacs 28

Tags: apt, emacs

I've installed emacs28 from snapshot (emacs-snapshot-common) without realizing it's the latest bleeding edge and not the latests stable version. 
I tries installing 26.3 from Kevin Kelly's repo, as described [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/install-gnu-emacs-26-1-ubuntu-18-04-16-04-18-10/), but got an error:

```
Unpacking emacs26-common (26.3~1.git96dd019-kk1+18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs26-common_26.3~1.git96dd019-kk1+18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/emacs-module.h', which is also in package emacs-snapshot-common 20200427:100116-e49d3a4~ubuntu18.04.1
```

I then tried to uninstall both of them but I get:

```
jonathan@DESKTOP-2VSOFC3:~$ sudo apt-get remove emacs-snapshot-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-snapshot : Depends: emacs-snapshot-common (= 20200427:100116-e49d3a4~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 emacs26 : Depends: emacs26-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried:

```
 sudo dpkg-divert --package emacs26 --divert /usr/include//emacs-module.h.moved --rename /usr/include/emacs-module.h
```

but that didn't help either...

I'd really appreciate any help getting out of this mess.
Thanks!

EDIT: somehow, running remove again for both versions worked, but I still get the same error trying to install emacs-26... while running "emacs&" returns:

```
 emacs-28.0.50: command not found
```

So now I'm completely without a working version of emacs :'(

Answer (score 0):

[How to Install GNU Emacs 26.1 in Ubuntu 18.04, 16.04, 18.10](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/install-gnu-emacs-26-1-ubuntu-18-04-16-04-18-10/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
sudo apt update
sudo apt install emacs26
```